# CefSharp Winforms - Execute javascript before showing browser

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I am trying to load a page and execute some JavaScript before showing the browser to the user. This because I want to take them through some screens before they get it shown (selenium like), and I only want to show it when I require their input (Which is after the 2nd pageload).

Unfortunately I can't go to that page directly, I have to click a link first. But whatever I try, it will still show the browser, then execute the JavaScript. My current test is below, was playing around with browser.visible, but that doesn't work either, I still see the js being executed.

(Site and JavaScript are dummy values)

```
 public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
        public void InitBrowser()
        {
            Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.bing.com/");
            this.Controls.Add(browser);
            browser.Visible = false;
            browser.FrameLoadEnd += (sender, args) =>
            {
                //Wait for the MainFrame to finish loading
                if (args.Frame.IsMain)
                {
                    //do this first
                    browser.ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPageLoaded("document.getElementById('sb_form_q').value = 'test';",true);
                    browser.ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPageLoaded("document.getElementById('sb_form_go').click();",true);
                    
                }
            };
            browser.FrameLoadEnd += (sender, args) =>
            {
                //Wait for the MainFrame to finish loading
                if (args.Frame.IsMain)
                {
                    //when page is loaded again, do this:
                    browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('hplogo').src='https://logos-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/bing-tm-logo.png'");
                    
                }
            };
            //then show browser again
            browser.Visible = true;
        }
```

Comment: You are setting `Visible = false` then adding actions to events (not executing the actions) then setting `Visible = true` when the events might not have fired yet.
Try putting `browser.Visible = true` within one of the events or create a new event to trigger it to show or use `.ContinueWith( () => { browser.Visible = true; } );`

Comment: You can connect `Puppeteer Sharp` to a running instance for automation purposes. Your code doesn't handle the `FrameLoadEnd` event properly, subscribing twice doesn't mean first run will be first handler, second will be second handler. Both handlers will fire. You have to subscribe, unsubscribe, subscribe a different handler. Or just check the frame url in the one handler.

Comment: How can i check the frameurl in a handler? .Adress doesnt exist according to VS

Comment: http://cefsharp.github.io/api/67.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_IFrame_Url.htm